# Is there some sort of Laravel Controller cache?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-cache

Weird problem I'm having with Laravel 5.5

I can update and even delete a controller and yet it appears as if a cached / old version is still being called.

I've tried clearing cache, clearing route cache, clearing config cache -
 doesn't seem to have any effect.

On my local test environment if I delete the controller file then try to access it I immediately get a not found error. On my production server I do not.

Anyone have any ideas or advice?

Answer (score 4):

You can try running:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

and

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and

```
php artisan route:cache
```

and if you are running queues:

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

Also be aware the errors you are getting might be different depending on `APP_ENV` or `APP_DEBUG` in your `.env` file but maybe that's not the case.

Comment: @JeremyJacob Maybe stupid question - are you sure you deployed new code into live server? Try running also `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: yes, tried the route:cache command, no change.
This is crazy - I've now deleted the entire 'Controllers' directory and there is no change.
I'm definitely accessing the right server, as renaming the 'public' directory causes a 404 not found error.

Comment: Is it possible you are using some other server like Cloudflare for example for caching?

Comment: @JeremyJacob After deleting controller, what `php artisan route:list` shows?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. As for me, the reason was in composer classLoader.

```
composer clear-cache
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 1):

For me I had the same mistake, tried everything but didnt help. Finally it turned out the browser was caching the get request which was sent. I tried clear application data by browser, but this did not help. Although looking the website in incognito mode, it was working as expected.

Finally I solved with by adding a timestamp to such get request where this caching happened.

```
 href="{{route('my-route').'?timestamp='.\Illuminate\Support\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright don't know what the problem was but deleting the 'Http' directory in 'App' and re ftping did the trick.

Comment: This is really strange. I believe nothing connected to Laravel but something with your server or the way you deployed your changes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once, because i had placed a "CustomController2" along with a "CustomController", just because i didn't want to the delete the previows one in case of failure.

I deleted the second one and cleared the route cache, and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because of htaccess. I commented this line and problem solved:

**ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"**

Files were cached by browser:

```
## EXPIRES HEADER CACHING ##

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
##ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES HEADER CACHING ##
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did as suggested by the other solutions contributed here but nothing happened. I had to refresh the Wamp Server I was using and that was it, it started working fine again.