# data not passing into view

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to add forgot password function in laravel, when i click reset password link it shows error "Undefined variable: title (View:". I have defined title in controller but still its showing this error. seems that passed data is not availabe in the view but its availble in forgot view.

my ResetPasswordController.php is

```
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function reset(Request $request) {
        $data['title'] = "Reset";

        return view('auth.passwords.reset',$data);
    }  

}
```

Forgot Password Works fine which has same @layout.app which has this 'title' variable, but Reset is not working. Following is code for route

```
Route::get('/password/forgot', [ 'as' => 'forgot', 'uses' => 'ForgotPasswordController@reset']);
Route::get('/password/reset', [ 'as' => 'reset', 'uses' => 'ResetPasswordController@reset']);
```

and view is

```
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ $title }}</title>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-laravel">
            <div class="container"> 
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{Config::get('constants.APP_TITLE')}}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>


                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul>


                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('users.index') }}">Manage Users</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('roles.index') }}">Manage Role</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('products.index') }}">Manage Product</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>


                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>


                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>


        <main class="py-4">
            <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this working in forgot password view but gives error in reset password view

I have also tried

```
$title = "Reset";
    return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with('title', $title);
```

Comment: Before your question gets closed for the 2nd time, what is different between the ResetPassword Controller and the ForgotPasswordController.  I would also mention, that  you don't need to have 2 controllers. You could have a PasswordController and put both functions in there.

Comment: difference is they have different view thats it.

Comment: Then provide the full code for /auth/passwords/reset.blade.php

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: i have manually cleared the view cache in storage/view

Comment: try the things [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904156/is-there-some-sort-of-laravel-controller-cache) one at a time

Comment: is this problem with url because reset link is like https://exampple.com/password/reset/f1a7d550b78e7af05ed1c9fa303caf05b3c61c9b5eb5eb2d815af6d11809f?email=gmail.com but route is password/reset only and not with the token . how to add token to the route?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  With that said, if you need a parameter to be passed, then in the route  `Route::get('/password/reset/{token}` and your controller needs that parameter defined:  `public function reset(Request $request, $token) ...

Comment: tried php artisan view:clear it still not working

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
return view('auth.passwords.reset',compact('data'));
```

Comment: what is dd($data)

Comment: in your reset function write `dd($data)`

Comment: same error but on going https://example.com/password/reset only link it shows array:1 [▼
  "title" => "Reset"
]    i think its problem of url capturing

Comment: In your view write this '{{dd($data)}}'

Comment: @vishalpanchal according to previous comment what is the output after dd

Comment: i got that where is problem, script is using illuminate which has already set route password/reset . i have modified file directly and its now passing data to view. is it good to modify it directly? its located at /home/portal/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable into the view like answer by A.A.Noman or else you can do it like this.

```
return view('auth.passwords.reset',['data' => $data] );
```